# Ошибка не все пути к коду возвращают значение. Программа требует на вход число, если данное число присутствует в массиве, то возвращает его индекс

Tags: c#, массивы, функции, циклы, методы

```
using System; 

namespace Lessons;

class Program3
{
         static int IndexOf(int[] myArray, int value)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if(myArray[i] == value)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray  = { 2, -5, 23, 55};
        IndexOf(myArray, 100);
        int result = IndexOf(myArray, 23);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) добавьте метку языка; 2) Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Я внес правки

Comment: Где же основная правка?:-) Вы же тестовые примеры не привели. Например, "Я ввожу -5, на выходе ожидаю 2, как индекс, а программа вместо этого пишет :"Уплатите налоги!" Я их срочно уплатил, но ничего не изменилось, 2 на выходе так и не печатает".

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставиь зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 1):

Метод должен вернуть `int`. Но если `if` внутри цикла не сработает, то ничего не вернётся. Об этом и говорит ошибка. Как минимум в конце метода надо поставить ещё один `return` с каким-то значением по-умолчанию

Comment: Написал как фиксить. .............."В видео такой ошибки не было" --- уверен, что там что-то было, только вы не увидели

Comment: Заработало. Большое спасибо

Comment: @VladislavBaranovskii выберите ответ как верный. галочку